# Qual fórmula eu uso Excel, para entrada e saída de produtos?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma pequena tabela, onde o 'QTD_E' = Entrada e 'QTD_S' = Saída, para cada retirada da quantidade de produto na 'QTD_E' eu queria acrescentar quantos produtos foram retirados no 'QTD_S', que fórmula eu uso para acrescentar um valor no 'QTD_S' de acordo com a retirada dos valores de quantidade do 'QTD_E', ??[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: https://github.com/EnioAmarantes/ControleEstoque Pra isso pode ser algo mais elaborado. Tem uma planilha que fiz pra controle de Estoque em excel nesse repositório. Dá uma olhada nas tabelas que usei talvez te ajude então!

Comment: Legal sua Planilha de estoque é bem simples. Eu não tenho conhecimento em fluxo de estoques de produtos, apenas estudo fórmulas avançadas de Excel de forma pura, sem objetivo de formar algo completo. Demorei um estante para entender, mas ela serviu para o meu caso

Comment: @EnioAmarantes quando puder disponibilizar uma resposta completa aqui, me dá o toque para poder lê-la. O assunto me interessou e no celular não é muito legal ler no GitHub, mas aqui no Stack Overflow já me acostumei